# How to record sound with Audacity in Ubuntu Studio 13.04

Tags: microphone, ubuntu-studio, audacity

Please help me figure out the problem with my sound problem. I have tried a lot of solutions, non of which seems to work for my case.
Here is the audio device viewed by Audacity:

```
==============================
Default capture device number: 15
Default playback device number: 15
==============================
Device ID: 0
Device name: HDA Intel: ALC662 rev1 Analog (hw:0,0)
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 2
Output channels: 6
Low Input Latency: 0,011610
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: 0,046440
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    44100
    48000
    96000
==============================
Device ID: 1
Device name: HDA Intel: ALC662 rev1 Analog (hw:0,2)
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 2
Output channels: 0
Low Input Latency: 0,011610
Low Output Latency: -1,000000
High Input Latency: 0,046440
High Output Latency: -1,000000
Supported Rates:
==============================
Device ID: 2
Device name: HDA NVidia: HDMI 0 (hw:1,3)
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 8
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    32000
    44100
    48000
    88200
    96000
    176400
    192000
==============================
Device ID: 3
Device name: HDA NVidia: HDMI 0 (hw:1,7)
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 8
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    32000
    44100
    48000
    88200
    96000
    176400
    192000
==============================
Device ID: 4
Device name: HDA NVidia: HDMI 0 (hw:1,8)
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 8
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    32000
    44100
    48000
    88200
    96000
    176400
    192000
==============================
Device ID: 5
Device name: HDA NVidia: HDMI 0 (hw:1,9)
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 8
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    32000
    44100
    48000
    88200
    96000
    176400
    192000
==============================
Device ID: 6
Device name: sysdefault
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 128
Output channels: 128
Low Input Latency: 0,042653
Low Output Latency: 0,042653
High Input Latency: 0,046440
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    8000
    9600
    11025
    16000
    22050
    32000
    44100
    48000
    88200
    176400
==============================
Device ID: 7
Device name: front
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 6
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    44100
    48000
    96000
==============================
Device ID: 8
Device name: surround40
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 6
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    44100
    48000
    96000
==============================
Device ID: 9
Device name: surround41
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 128
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    44100
    48000
    96000
==============================
Device ID: 10
Device name: surround50
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 128
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    44100
    48000
    96000
==============================
Device ID: 11
Device name: surround51
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 6
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    44100
    48000
    96000
==============================
Device ID: 12
Device name: surround71
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 6
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    44100
    48000
    96000
==============================
Device ID: 13
Device name: pulse
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 32
Output channels: 32
Low Input Latency: 0,011610
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: 0,046440
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    8000
    9600
    11025
    12000
    15000
    16000
    22050
    24000
    32000
    44100
    48000
    88200
    96000
    176400
    192000
==============================
Device ID: 14
Device name: dmix
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 0
Output channels: 2
Low Input Latency: -1,000000
Low Output Latency: 0,042667
High Input Latency: -1,000000
High Output Latency: 0,042667
Supported Rates:
    48000
==============================
Device ID: 15
Device name: default
Host name: ALSA
Input channels: 32
Output channels: 32
Low Input Latency: 0,011610
Low Output Latency: 0,011610
High Input Latency: 0,046440
High Output Latency: 0,046440
Supported Rates:
    8000
    9600
    11025
    12000
    15000
    16000
    22050
    24000
    32000
    44100
    48000
    88200
    96000
    176400
    192000
==============================
Selected capture device: 13 - pulse
Selected playback device: 13 - pulse
Supported Rates:
    8000
    9600
    11025
    12000
    15000
    16000
    22050
    24000
    32000
    44100
    48000
    88200
    96000
    176400
    192000
==============================
Available mixers:
==============================
Available capture sources:
0 - Mic:0
1 - Line:0
2 - Mic:1
3 - Line:1
==============================
Available playback volumes:
0 - Master:0
1 - PCM:0
2 - Front:0
3 - Surround:0
4 - Center:0
5 - LFE:0
6 - Line:0
7 - Mic:0
8 - Mic Boost:0
==============================
Capture volume is native
Playback volume is native
```

I have tried with arecord test.wav and still no result. Testing it in windows all works normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about **Ubunbtu-Studio**.
But I do for **Audacity**:

Set Audacity to use **Pulse**
[image]
in edit | preferences:
[image]

Then you need to correct your **Pulse** settings:

1. launch some music on your computer
2. start a recording on **Audacity**
3. open **Pulse**
   [image]
4. go in 2<sup>nd</sup> tab (recording) make sure that Alsa plugin is capturing: <kbd>Monitor of Audio interne Stereo analogique</kbd> (or something like that depending on your language)
   [image]

and now you can record:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Boris. I have followed your instructions and all works well when I want to register sound from any other application. The problem with microphone not working still remains. No sound input in audacity or any other application that uses a microphone

Comment: @LucianMarian I suggest you to [mark this answer as accepted](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). And create a different question for your micro problem.

Comment: @LucianMarian for the micro problem, I suggest you to include in your question pictures of your pulse settings, it could be the source of the problem.